# Which parts of the head should be covered by the kippa?

Tags: halacha, minhag, kippa-yarmulka, head

I understand that it is a widespread minhag for men to wear a head covering. Recently I have seen kippot covering different portions of the head. So please tell me which parts of the head should be covered by the kippa?

Comment: I think the right question is, what percentage of the head must be covered.

Answer (score 6):

Halacha Berurah says that your kippah should cover the majority of your head, and if you can't do that much, then it should at least be visible from all sides.

Comment: Majority of the head? Even a wig doesn't: the face and the underside of the chin is most of the head, I think. Or does it mean the majority of the crown of the head? In that case, it's possible to cover the majority without the _kipa_'s being visible from all sides. Or does it mean the majority of the hair (or where hair was before balding, if relevant)?

Comment: cover the majority of the part where the hair grows

Comment: He just says ראש.

Comment: I mean Y"Y siman 91

Answer (score 4):

Rav M Feinstein held that a hand's worth is enough, as the question is raised in the Talmud whether one can use one's own hand to cover his head. (The answer is no, IIRC, but the hava amina proves the point.)

Comment: +1. Do you have a citation to R'MF?

Comment: So it does not matter if say only the front of the head is covered?

Comment: IgM the very first one, OH I 1. I did not review the text before posting. I think some clarification of his position is in order, there may be more there, but I'm short on time

Comment: BTW, the reason you can't use your hand is become something can not "cover" itself. Your hand can't cover your head because it's all the same "thing"

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked. ("_Which parts of the head should be covered?"_)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/shiur.asp?id=1950
3 - שיעור הכיפה

שאלה חשובה היא, האם ישנו שיעור מסויים לגודלה של הכיפה. רבי שלמה קלוגר, שהיה אחד מגדולי הפוסקים לפני כמאה וחמישים שנה, כתב שלגלות לגמרי את הראש אסור מן הדין, ואפילו פחות מד' אמות, אסור ללכת בראש מגולה לגמרי. ומנהג החסידות שהתפשט בישראל הוא שלא לילך יותר מד' אמות ללא כיסוי של רוב הראש. כלומר לדעתו הכיפה צריכה להיות בגודל כזה שתכסה לפחות את רוב הראש.
אולם מרבית הפוסקים חלקו עליו, ודחו את ראיותיו, וכתבו שמצד הדין אין חיוב לחבוש כיפה שתכסה את רוב הראש. ואביא לפניכם את סיכום ההלכה מדברי האגרות משה ,או"ח ח"א א') : הרוצה להחמיר ולחוש לדעת הגאון ר' שלמה קלוגר, צריך לחבוש כיפה גדולה שתכסה את רוב ראשו, אבל מצד הדין אין חיוב לחשוש לדעתו, כיון שהיא דעת יחיד. ובפרט שכל יסוד חבישת הכיפה מבוסס על מנהג חסידות. ולכן אם הכיפה מכסה באופן שנקרא שראשו מכוסה, רשאים לילך כך ברחוב, ואף לברך ברכות, וכמו שעושין כן רבים, ואין להחשיבם חס וחלילה לקלים, עד כאן דבריו.
וגם בתשובות ישכיל עבדי (ח"ו ע' קצ-ב) הסכים שאין חיוב לכסות את רוב הראש, אולם כתב שלכל הפחות צריך שהכיפה תראה מכל צדדי הראש.

R Ovadia Yosef it has to be seen from all sides of the head but neednt cover most of the head. R Shlomo Kluger says it does have to cover most of the head. RMF says there is no harm in covering the most part but its not necessary.