# In terms of kippot, has there ever been a debate regarding what part of the head needed to be covered?

Tags: kippa-yarmulka, head-covering

You typically see Kippot worn two different ways.

- [Either on the very top of one's head. (child on right)](https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ffthmb.tqn.com%2Fa46gwG7Js7hOhpaWnC63Ly2Vdbc%3D%2F1280x888%2Ffilters%3Ano_upscale()%3Afill(auto%2C1)%2Fabout%2F852425-56a55f615f9b58b7d0dc9075.jpg&f=1)
- [Or on the back of one's head (on what you might consider the "point" of the skull)](https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mayaworks.org%2Fmedia%2Fcatalog%2Fproduct%2Fcache%2F5%2Fimage%2F1200x1200%2F9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95%2Fs%2Fu%2Fsunburst_burgandy_head.jpg&f=1) - **(This being most common, at least from what I've seen)**

I was curious about any debates which may have occurred historically on the proper way of wearing kippot. Has there been historical disagreement or has this not been a huge topic of debate in judaism?

Comment: Presumably you do not mean to ask strictly about the dichotomy as stated - between historical disagreement and not being a huge debate, but about the range of opinions on the matter, if they exist. Is that right? If so this might be a duplicate of [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11004/3).

Answer (score 0):

The Shu"t Aseilecha Rav (ביוגרפיה - עשה לך רב
R. Chaim David son of R. Moshe Ha - Levi) writes:
שו"ת עשה לך רב חלק ז - שאלות ותשובות בקיצור סימנים עד-עה-עו
ג) לא נכון שמעת שכיסוי הראש "חייב" להיות שיכסה את רובו. והנה ב"עשה לך רב" חלק ראשון סימן כ"ז כתבתי בעיקר חיוב כיסוי הראש אם הוא מן הדין, וציינתי שם דעת הפוסקים בענין, אבל לא כתבתי בענין השיעור (כי לא נשאלתי על כך באותה שאלה שהיתה שידור ברדיו), אבל רמזתי בסוף התשובה שדי אף אם "קטנה" היא עיין שם. וזה משום שלענ"ד יש לפסוק כסברת מרן החיד"א ורבים מגדוה"פ הסוברים שאין זו אלא ממדת חסידות, ולכן אין להקפיד ביותר על גודל הכיפה, אף שיש להקפיד עד מאד על עצם כיסוי הראש, וביחוד בימינו שלענ"ד יש בדבר משום צד איסור להולך בגילוי - ראש, מן הטעם שכתבתי בחלק ראשון קחנו משם. ובודאי שכיסוי כל הראש או רובו היא מדת חסידות וראוי לנהוג כן, אך ממדת הדין די שהכיפה נראית ואינה קטנה ביותר, פרט לשעת התפלה שיש לכסות הראש בכובע ולכל הפחות בכיפה גדולה המכסה כל הראש ולפחות רובו.

The Basic Halacha is that it should be visible from all sides, and not smaller than that.  It is a midas Chassidus to have a Kippah that is bigger than that. 
He says that today one should not go out without a kippah.  However, in many locations in the world, there would be a severe danger to one's life, one should wear a baseball cap.

Comment: Where does he say that it needs to be visible **from all sides**?

Comment: To add to your last sentence: Or a simple beanie (which is especially handy during colder winter montgs).

Comment: אך ממדת הדין די שהכיפה נראית ואינה קטנה ביותר

Comment: Right. It needs to be visible and not overly small. Doesn’t necessarily mean that it needs to be visible from every side.

Comment: It needs to be *visible* to whom?  Certainly *any size is visible* it depends where you're looking.  The fact that he doesn't mention any particular side, and that visibility is critical to the size (anything less is too small), that means it needs to be seen on all sides.